# How to write a recursive definition for the constant function?

Tags: logic, recursion, recursive-algorithms

I know that we can define the constant function as a function $f: \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ by lettting:

$f(0) = c$

$f(n+1) = c$

Let $g = z$ so that $g(n) = 0$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$

Let $h = s$

Let $h_1 = \pi_n^n$

Then we can write a recursive definition of the constant function $f: \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ as follows:

$f(0) = h_1(g, s(g), s(s(g)), s(s(s(g)))...)$

$f(n) = h_1(g, s(g), s(s(g)), s(s(s(g)))...)$

Am I on the right track here?

Comment: It's slightly easier to simply define $f(n+1)=f(n)$ for the recursive case.

Comment: Thanks, have edited. Is my answer correct now? I'm a little unsure about using the "...", not sure if this is allowed or not.

Comment: However, if you just want to prove that the constant function is primitive recursive, you don't actually need to make a recursive definition -- by definition, a composition of p.r. functions is p.r., and the function you're looking for is simply $$ s \circ s \circ \cdots \circ s \circ z $$ for appropriately many $s$s.